# Printing CPLEX eliminated rows, columns and substitutions

Tags: java, optimization, linear-programming, cplex

I am using Java API of CPLEX optimization software. After the solver finishes the optimization, it prints the solution and the parameters of the LP as well:

```
MIP Presolve eliminated 282 rows and 230 columns.
Aggregator did 14 substitutions
```

How to observe these eliminated rows and columns? Is there a built-in function in the API?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the presolved/reduced model with the C API, but you cannot with the Java API or Concert in general.  In the Java API there is the [PresolveCallback](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refjavacplex/html/ilog/cplex/IloCplex.PresolveCallback.html), but this is not so friendly to use (i.e., it is invoked several times during a solve and you don't necessarily know which invocation is the one you want).  It may be worth looking at quickly in case it suits your needs.

Another technique of obtaining this information would be to redirect the CPLEX log into your own stream (using the [setOut](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSA5P_12.7.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refjavacplex/html/ilog/cplex/IloCplex.html?view=kc#setOut(java.io.OutputStream)) method) and parse out lines that look like "MIP Presolve eliminated XXX rows and XXX columns".  You can find examples of this [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=631de51c-d8f9-4221-b32d-5ec2eec5ac10&ps=25) and [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=e6f59afe-6c64-4580-8e36-1c9e8eb6ba7f&ps=25).  This is more of a general java programming technique (not really CPLEX related), so I won't attempt to provide more code snippets for that here.